# How to make a horizontal icon bar with HTML

Tags: html, firefox

I'm trying to make a horizontal icon bar with HTML. I'm using the following code, and at 100% it's ok, but, with Firefox, if I zoom out three times, the last "icon" goes into a new line.

How do I fix this?

```css
.icon-bar {
  z-index: 9999999999;
  width: 336px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Overflow due to float */
}

.icon-bar a {
  float: left;
  /* Float links side by side */
  text-align: center;
  /* Center-align text */
  width: 13.6%;
  /* Equal width */
  padding: 6px 0;
  /* Some top and bottom padding */
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  /* Add transition for hover effects */
  color: navy;
  border-left: 1px solid navy;
  border-right: 1px solid navy;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#">A</a>
  <a href="#">B</a>
  <a href="#">C</a>
  <a href="#">D</a>
  <a href="#">E</a>
  <a href="#">F</a>
  <a href="#">G</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does simply have something to do with it not being responsive. You should use Media Queries, to change the width of `.icon-bar`.

Here is an example on a media querie:

```
/* Set the background color of body to tan */
body {
  background-color: tan;
}

/* On screens that are 992px or less, set the background color to blue */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

You can read more about queries here: [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: I've read about Media queries, but I don't understand how they could help me to fix my example. In my example the space needed exists, so I don't think I should enlarge the width of .icon-bar

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid the px width. Just use 100%
Second, your math is wrong because of the 1px border (is breaking your menu)
Get rid of it and you are all set! (The menu width is then adjusted to 14.2%)

```css
.icon-bar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #efefef;
    overflow: auto;
    /* Overflow due to float */
}

.icon-bar a {
    float: left;
    /* Float links side by side */
    text-align: center;
    /* Center-align text */
    width: 14.2%;
    /* Equal width */
    padding: 6px 0;
    /* Some top and bottom padding */
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    /* Add transition for hover effects */
    color: navy;
    /*border-left: 1px solid navy;
        border-right: 1px solid navy;*/
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```